# Access to Azure Database

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I have created an Access 2013 web app which creates an Azure SQL database behind the scenes on our O365 SharePoint web site.  I can access this database using SSMS studio (I have the professional version not the express version).

I would like to link to the Azure database tables or be able to copy the database.  The reason for this is that I cannot create views in the Azure database and the Access web app is too limited for our external reporting needs.  We don't need to create views or tables in the Azure database we only need to access the information stored in its tables.

Whenever I try to right click on the Azure database to perform a task I receive the following error.

Cannot open server 'xxxxxxx' requested by the login. Client with IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=40615&LinkId=20476

The provided link is useless, it contains no information (There is no additional information about this issue in the Error and Event Log Messages or Knowledge Base databases at this time).

How do I take care of this error or how can I link to the Azure SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

When viewing your database in the Azure management portal, there is an option on the right hand side that says `Manage allowed IP addresses`. That link will take you to a page where you can enter IP addresses that will be allowed through the firewall.

Here's a link to the MSDN article: [How to: Configure Firewall Settings (Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj553530.aspx)

> **Manage Server-Level Firewall Rules through Transact-SQL**
>
> 1. Launch a query window through the Management Portal or through SQL
>      Server Management Studio.
> 2. Verify you are connected to the **master** database
> 3. Server-level firewall rules can be created, updated, or deleted from within the query window
>
>    - To create or update server-level firewall rules, execute the sp_set_firewall rule stored procedure. The following example enables a range of IP addresses on the server Contoso.

```
   EXEC sp_set_firewall_rule @name = N'ContosoFirewallRule', @start_ip_address = '192.168.1.1', @end_ip_address = '192.168.1.10'
```

Comment: Zeroef,Thank you for your quick reply.  This will probably sond very stupid but how do I get to the Azure management portal.  We did not create the Azure database, it was created for us when we created the Access 2013 web app.

Comment: That's a tough one. You'll need the Microsoft account that it was created with or have the owner grant you access. Once that happens you can visit http://manage.windowsazure.com to login.

Comment: @FiliepSamyn - I just added the steps to add the firewall rule using T-SQL in SSMS

Comment: Zeroef 
I tried the set firewall already (code pasted below) exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'Allow Windows Azure','0.0.0.0','0.0.0.0'; based on the note Windows Azure connection attempts are allowed when both this field and the start_ip_address field equals 0.0.0.0. However this returns the following error Msg 5001, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_set_firewall_rule, Line 1
User must be in the master database.

Comment: @FiliepSamyn - Ha. I haven't had enough coffee yet! You wouldn't be able to connect with SSMS until you have access. You're going to need to change the rules via the web portal.

Comment: When I run sys.database_firewall_rules I get the following error
Msg 2809, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The request for procedure 'database_firewall_rules' failed because 'database_firewall_rules' is a view object.
My problem is where is the web portal for this?  I have signed up for a trial SQL Azure account but that does not get me to the database that is on our SharePoint O365 site.